Did Jesus tacitly accept the Roman Centurion’s statement on his ALSO being under authority?
When the Roman Centurion said that he was also under authority, did Jesus accept his statement as truth since he, Jesus, did not contradict him?

Matthew 8:8-10
American Standard Version
9 For I also am a man under authority, having under myself soldiers: and I say to this one, Go, and he goeth; and to another, Come, and he cometh; and to my servant, Do this, and he doeth it.


Matthew 8:8-10
Christian Standard Bible
9 For I too am a man under authority, having soldiers under my command. I say to this one, ‘Go,’ and he goes; and to another, ‘Come,’ and he comes; and to my servant, ‘Do this!’ and he does it.”

Was this the same authority that the crowds recognized that Jesus possessed when he healed a crippled man?

John 5:26-27
New International Version
26 For as the Father has life in himself, so he has granted the Son also to have life in himself. 27 And he has given him authority to judge because he is the Son of Man.

and the same authority that God gave Jesus to judge?

John 5:26-27
New International Version
26 For as the Father has life in himself, so he has granted the Son also to have life in himself. 27 And he has given him authority to judge because he is the Son of Man.

What does the giving of authority show about the relationship of Jesus with His Father?
RESEARCH
NIV Cultural Backgrounds Study Bible
8:9 a man under authority. The centurion understands how authority works: just as soldiers obey the centurion because he is backed by the authority of the empire, everything will obey Jesus because he is backed by God’s authority (cf. 9:6,8; 28:18).
NIV Biblical Theology Study Bible
5:26–27 These verses explain how the Son can (1) generate resurrection life by his powerful word and (2) exercise divine judgment (vv. 21–25): the Father authorized him to do both.

Matthew 28:18
New International Version
18 Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me.

NKJV MacArthur Study Bible, 2nd Edition
28:18 All authority. See 11:27; John 3:35. Absolute sovereign authority—lordship over all—is handed to Christ, “in heaven and on earth.” This is clear proof of His deity. The time of His humiliation was at an end, and God had exalted Him above all (Phil. 2:9–11).  (see Scriptures below)

Matthew 28:18
New International Version
18 Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me.


Matthew 11:27
New International Version
27 “All things have been committed to me by my Father. No one knows the Son except the Father, and no one knows the Father except the Son and those to whom the Son chooses to reveal him.


John 3:35
New International Version
35 The Father loves the Son and has placed everything in his hands.


Huh? The centurion was referring to the authority structure of the Roman army. Of course that's not the same authority as what Jesus possessed!

I am confused about exactly what you are asking!!  Of course, the centurion was a man under authority - he was a soldier who received and gave orders.  Can you make this question more focused?

@Dottard, I think the key word here is "also," implying that Jesus was able to heal by means of his being under authority. This reminds me of an accusation by the Pharisees that Jesus was working under his own initiative and not under authority.

@Dieter. The original Greek word order is "I a man am under authority; having under me soldiers also; I say …".
The "also" relates to the "under" and "over", not to Jesus's position. Many English translations put the "also" in a very misleading and inappropriate position within the sentence.
See my answer to … questions concerning the use or non-use of the conjunction kai at Matthew 8:9.

@Ray Butterworth, Great point, and it poses the question of why the Centurion's statement astonished Jesus. What did it indicate about the Centurion's expectations?  Taken into full context, it seems that the Centurion was fully aware of Judean customs toward gentiles and he implied that Jesus had the authority to command the servant's healing similar to how the Centurion commanded his soldiers. Gary Habermas asserts that Thomas's use of the word, Lord, in John 20:28 had a greater weight than "my God." Thank you for the link regarding the use of kai in this case.

I appreciate all your comments and insights.

Short Answer: I would say that Jesus did accept his statement as true. However, they were under different authorities. Jesus was under the authority of the Father, and the centurion was under Roman authority. That being said, I believe that the centurion recognized Jesus' authority.
Matthew 8:8-10 NKJV

8 The centurion answered and said, “Lord, I am not worthy that You
should come under my roof. But only speak a word, and my servant will
be healed. 9 For I also am a man under authority, having soldiers
under me. And I say to this one, ‘Go,’ and he goes; and to another,
‘Come,’ and he comes; and to my servant, ‘Do this,’ and he does it.”
10 When Jesus heard it, He marveled, and said to those who followed,
“Assuredly, I say to you, I have not found such great faith, not even
in Israel!

What did the centurion believe?
1. Lord
The centurion's reference to Jesus as "Lord" provides insight into his perception of Jesus. In Greek culture, "kurios" was employed to denote a master or owner, to reference God or gods, and as a title for someone sovereign, a prince, chief, or the Roman emperor. It is a title of honor, expressive of respect and reverence, with which servants salute their master.
It is significant to note that a Roman centurion, an officer in the Roman army overseeing and administrating Israel during this period, referred to Jesus, a Jewish man, as "Lord." In other words, he exhibited great submission. It seems to perhaps imply recognition of Jesus in terms of mastery, ownership, or supreme authority.
2. only speak a word
By comparing his own authority over soldiers to Jesus' authority over sickness and demons, it seems clear that the centurion recognized Jesus' divine authority.
3. be healed
The centurion clearly believed that Jesus had the power and authority to heal, an authority that the centurion did not possess himself; if he did, why ask Jesus?
4. such great faith
It was an act of faith. Faith so great that Jesus had not found it in Israel.

What authority did Jesus have?
Matthew 28:18 NKJV

18 And Jesus came and spoke to them, saying, “All authority has been
given to Me in heaven and on earth.

What authority did the centurion have?

The Centurion was responsible for the well-being and training of all
of the soldiers in his century. This included setting watches,
assigning work, and making sure his troops got their share of supplies
from the camp quartermaster. A Centurion also led his troops in battle
and was responsible for giving them courage.

Conclusion:
All means all. No one else had the same authority that Jesus did. Only he had it all. The Roman centurion had authority, but Jesus had divine authority. The centurion was a soldier, not a judge, but Jesus had all authority, including the right to judge.

You’re overthinking the simplicity of the scenario. Jesus told the centurion that he would come with him, but the centurion was content to take his word that what he said would be done would be done. He himself was a man who received orders from a superior, and was himself a superior to others. In his own world, when he commands someone, or is commanded by someone above him, that command is carried out. It doesn’t require the one issuing the command to follow or verify. The one giving the command expects that what is commanded will be performed. Ergo, “You don’t need to come. If you command the sickness, over which you have authority, I expect it to obey, just as I obey my superiors, and just as my subordinates obey me.”

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

True, but the unfortunately the original question is actually about the use of the word "also", which in many English translations has an ambiguous meaning because of being placed in an inappropriate position in the sentence.  The Title question illustrates this easy misunderstanding.

An explanation of the expectations implicit in the exchange is the key to the answer about “also.” I understood the question. I felt that the answer wasn’t a matter of semantics, but of circumstance.
